# Behaviour of actionButton if called from server

Tags: r, shiny

Calling `actionButton` with `NULL` as button ID works fine in console (it just doesn't create an id):

```
> library(shiny)
> actionButton(NULL, "Label1")
<button type="button" class="btn btn-default action-button">Label1</button>
```

But calling it from server causes error:

```
Browse[1]> actionButton(NULL, "label1")
Error in exists(name, envir = private$values) : invalid first argument
```

example app:

```
ui <- function() {
  fluidPage()
  }

server <- function(input, output, session) {
  browser()
  }
runApp(list(ui = ui, server = server))
```

Can someone explain me this behaviour?

Comment: Type `exists(NULL)` in your console

Comment: `Error in exists(NULL) : invalid first argument` in both console and server breakpoint. Shouldn't it be like it?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Every element on `HTML` canvas has to have a unique `id` associated with it: http://www.w3.org/TR/html5/dom.html#the-id-attribute:

> The id attribute specifies its element's unique identifier (ID). The
>   value must be unique amongst all the IDs in the element's home subtree
>   and must contain at least one character. The value must not contain
>   any space characters.

Since you're trying to render something to a page using markup above rules apply for all `shiny` applications

Answer (score 0):

my best guess is that it is connected with *exists* function, that is called by the server on *inputId* parameter of *actionButton* function.

Look on error, please:

```
Listening on http://127.0.0.1:5515
Warning: Error in exists: invalid first argument
Stack trace (innermost first):
87: exists
86: self$exists
85: oldInputs$available
84: restoreInput
83: actionButton
82: renderUI [#10]
81: func
80: origRenderFunc
79: output$moreControls
 4: <Anonymous>
 3: do.call
 2: print.shiny.appobj
 1: <Promise>
```

and if you call:

```
> exists( NULL)
Error in exists(NULL) : invalid first argument
```

I used this code to generate aforementioned error message:

```
 if (interactive()) {

  ui <- fluidPage(
    uiOutput("moreControls")
  )

  server <- function(input, output) {
    output$moreControls <- renderUI({

        actionButton( NULL, "label1")

    })
  }
  shinyApp(ui, server)
}
```

Comment: Yeah, I get it. But why does the server call it? I tried to follow it inside the actionButton function to see where it happens - but it didn't work out for me, as it calls some function inside I couldn't get inside of.